# What is the difference between useEffect and code in the body of a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Basically I'm wondering what the difference is between these two things:

```
const myComponent = (props) => {
    console.log('hi');
    return (
        <div>props: {props}</div>
    );
};

const myComponent = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('hi');
    });
    return (
        <div>props: {props}</div>
    );
};
```

What exactly would trigger the log statement in each case?

Comment: The second one logs `hi` _after_ each time the component is re-rendered.

Comment: `console.log` is executed on every render in both cases. But I guess in the second case the log statement is executed after the rendering. Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` will delay the log because it won't be immediately executed.

See this example:

```
const MyComponent1 = () => {
    console.log('Hello');
    console.log('World');
    return (
        <div></div>
    );
};
```

This will output `Hello world`

```
const MyComponent2 = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Hello');
    });
    console.log("world")
    return (
        <div></div>
    );
};
```

This will output `world Hello`.

Watch this wonderful [video](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ) about the event loop if you want to have a clear understanding about this